# Log In Code Jquery Mobile using PHP

Tags: php

Hey I'm working on a Log In Code but apparently my query isnt running correctly. My login page is this:

```
<div data-role="page" id="login">



    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">       

    <?php
 session_start();

 include_once('config.php');

 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
  $email = trim($_POST['email']);
  $contraseña = trim($_POST['contraseña']);



$query = "SELECT * FROM `Usuarios` WHERE Email='$email' AND Contraseña='$contraseña' AND com_code IS NULL";

  /** $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error()); **/

  if($connect->query($query))
{
    echo '<p>Executed Successfully</p>';
} else {
    echo '<p>Error in execution</p>';
}



  /**$num_row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  if( $num_row ==1 )
         {
   $_SESSION['user_name']=$row['Nombre'];
   header("Location: pages/home.php");
   exit;
  }
  else
         {
    header("Location: services/invalid.php");
   exit;

  }**/
 }
?> 


    <div id="logo" style="text-align:center">

    <img src="img/LogoAzul.png" width="50%" height="auto">
    </div> <!------LOGO---->


        <form action="index.php" method="post">

        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="">

        <label for="contraseña">Contraseña:</label>
        <input type="text" name="contraseña" id="contraseña" value="">

        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <input type="checkbox" name="recuerdame" id="recuerdame">
        <label for="recuerdame">Recuerdame </label>
        </fieldset>


        <input type="submit" value="Entrar">

        </form>


       <p class="mc-top-margin-1-5"><a href="#recuperarcontraseña">¿Olvidaste tu contraseña?</a></p>

        <p class="mc-top-margin-1-5">¿No eres Usuario?  <a href="#nuevousuario">Registrate Aqui</a>.</p>
```

My config file looks like this:

```
<?php

    $host_name  = "*******************";
    $database   = "******";
    $user_name  = "******";
    $password   = "***********";

    $connect = new MySQLi($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);
    if ($connect->connect_errno) {
        die("Sorry, we are having some problems.");
    }


    $con = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

?>
```

I think the part that isnt working is executing the query if not it must be inside the php of the login page.

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

When you try to login you are looking for a form element with the name `submit`, but you don't have one. Add the name submit to your submit button and it should work fine.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Entrar">
```